# Automatically collapse rows and columns that sum to 0. Code running infinitely

Tags: excel, vba

My code is below.My objective is to automatically group and collapse rows where the sum of a certain range in those columns and rows = 0.  It runs indefinitely and I am not sure why. I think the issue may be with the line
**``If Application.Sum(Range("T11", "T89").Offset(0, L_Counter)) > 0 Then''** however I am not sure. Thanks

```vb
Sub Gantt_Chart_Format()
    Dim L_Counter
    Dim L_Val
    Dim R_Counter
    Dim R_Val
    Dim B_Val
    Dim B_Counter

    L_Counter = 0
    L_Val = 0
    R_Counter = 0
    R_Val = 0
    B_Val = 0
    B_Counter = 0

    While L_Val = 0
        If Application.Sum(Range("T11", "T89").Offset(0, L_Counter)) > 0 Then
            L_Val = L_Counter
        Else
            L_Counter = L_Counter + 1
        End If
    Wend

    While R_Val = 0
        If Application.Sum(Range("EJ1", "EJ89").Offset(0, -1 * R_Counter)) > 0 Then
            R_Val = R_Counter
        Else
            R_Counter = R_Counter + 1
        End If
    Wend
    
    While B_Val = 0
        If Application.Sum(Range("T89", "EJ89").Offset(-1 * B_Counter, 0)) > 0 Then
            B_Val = B_Counter
        Else
            B_Counter = B_Counter + 1
        End If
    Wend
    
    Target_Left_Column = 0
    Target_Left_Column = Range("T11").Offset(0, Left_Counter)
    Range("T11", Target_Cell).EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Columns.Group
    Target_Right_Column = 0
    Target_Right_Column = Range("EJ1").Offset(0, R_Counter)
    Range(Target_Right_Column, "EJ1").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Columns.Group
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1
    Target_Row = 0
    Target_Row = Range("T89").Offset(-1 * B_Counter, 0)
    Range(Target_Row).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Rows.Group
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: Please put comments on your code so that it will understandable for us. A pseudocode will be helpful.

Comment: step though your code (press F8 after placing the mouse cursor inside any valid statement) to see what statements are being processed and in what sequece
and query relevant variables by means of Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out). For instance once you are at `If Application.Sum(Range("T89", "EJ89").Offset(-1 * B_Counter, 0)) > 0 Then` code line you could type `?Application.Sum(Range("T89", "EJ89").Offset(-1 * B_Counter, 0))` in Immediate Window and press return to see the outcome